# Send email alert using Scrapy after multiple spiders have finished crawling

Tags: python, scrapy

Just wondering what is the best way to implement this. I have 2 spiders and I want to send an email alert depending on what is scraped after the 2 spiders have finished crawling.

I'm using a script based on the tutorial to run both spiders like so:

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":
    process = CrawlerProcess(get_project_settings())
    process.crawl(NqbpSpider)
    process.crawl(GladstoneSpider)
    process.start() # the script will block here until the crawling is finished
```

Is it best to call an email function after process.start() or to code up an email function in the pipelines.py file under the close_spider function

`def close_spider(self, spider):`

Answer (score 2):

You can use this

```
from scrapy import signals
from scrapy.xlib.pydispatch import dispatcher

class MySpider(CrawlSpider):
    def __init__(self):
        dispatcher.connect(self.spider_closed, signals.spider_closed)

    def spider_closed(self, spider):
      # second param is the instance of the spider about to be closed.
      #  Write the mail sending part here
```

If you want to include the scraped data with the mail, write the script in the pipelines.py file.

```
class MyPipeline(Pipeline):
    spider = None

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        if spider.name == 'Name of the spider':
            # Use the data and send the mail from here
        return item
```