# scrapy send email and attach csv file with scraped items

Tags: python, scrapy

I've got a couple of spiders working which save some scraped data into a csv file. I've also written an email function which will send an email notification once the spiders have finished crawling. However when I try to attach the csv output file it appears that the file is not updated until after the python script has exited. Is there any way around this? ie I want to attached the updated csv file with the scraped items.

Please see my example code below. My email function is called after process.start

```python
process = CrawlerProcess(get_project_settings())
process.crawl(Nqbp_Spider)
process.crawl(Gladstone_Spider)
process.start()
send_email() # this is my custom email function
```

Comment: you could write script which first runs script with scraper and later it runs your function (or other script which send email).

Comment: the best way to do it would in the pipeline so once the spider finishes (file written and closed) you can send, all you have to do is `def close(self)` in pipeline and put your function there

Comment: issue is I have 2 spiders. So I don't want 2 emails sent. Just one email after both have finished crawling. I assume I can't put the email function in pipelines.py because it would get executed twice?

Answer (score 0):

Write the mail script in the pipeline function does the work.
refer to this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60499455/send-email-alert-using-scrapy-after-multiple-spiders-have-finished-crawling/60499770#60499770)